VIM which "set" setting maintains cursor horizontal character position when navigating up/down lines?
Which VIM setting allows you to move vertically between lines and still save/maintain the current cursor's horizontal character position?
E.g.
  int variable1[*4]; // Cursor starts on "4"
  char c[3]*;        // Use "j" twice
  int variable2[*6]; // Should end up on "6" (does in VIM on MING and Unix)
  int varia*ble2[6]; // On VSCodeVim I end up here instead (see Background)

The function is referenced in this question: Cursor not returning to horizontal position in vim but not what I'm seeking (what is this setting "set" option).
Background: Both in my MINGW64 VIM > 9.0, and in my Unix VIM > 8.1 in normal mode it works fine. This has always worked fine and I have a large .vimrc. But in VSCodeVim plugin > v1.26 (!= VIM) where my VS VIM sharing the same .vimrc and .vim files, it does not work, so I'm trying to figure out step-1 which is what "set" setting controls this functionality in VIM to determine if it's truly a setting or something I need to setup in a custom fashion in VSCode?
The answer would be the :set setting that I can modify in VIM that changes this VIM behavior. If there is no setting and this is native operation, or it's a function instead that controls this feature, this would then be the answer otherwise.

See :help 'startofline', which may or may not be supported in VSCodeVim, which is not Vim.

@romainl thanks, that was a start, however whether I set this sol on or off, or compatible on or off, I can't force VIM to emulate what VSCodeVim is doing. I do realize VIM != the VSCodeVim plugin, which is why I wanted to understand what makes this work in VIM in the first place. Maybe it turns out VIM just works this way without a particular setting (seeing as I can't currently force it to operate otherwise) and it's therefore a plugin bug not emulating VIM correctly. The question is, ther4, what setting (or I guess function/etc.) makes VIM choose to reset the cursor position as it does.

I'm not aware of any setting in Vim that controls this. If you :h j and scroll to the bottom it says " The first two commands put the cursor in the same column (if possible) as it was after the last command that changed the column". I think it's just built in Vim behavior.
